# The mbstring extension is missing

Tags: php, mbstring

I'm new to linux. Installed apache2, mysql-server, php 7.0 and phpmyadmin on my Linux Mint 18.1.
Installation went fine, but localhost/phpmyadmin gives error (see title).

Tried:

- uncommenting "extension_dir" in php.ini
- uncommenting mbstring.dll extension in php.ini
- making link from /var/www/html/phpmyadmin to /usr/share/phpmyadmin
- reinstalling php7.0-mbstring

but neither worked.

I've been restarting Apache as well.

Comment: `mbstring.dll` is a Windows library, you need `mbstring.so`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Apache and PHP running correctly, you should install the mbstring extension on PHP and restart Apache:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
sudo service httpd restart
```

Restarting Apache is a step that most people forget about. Some distributions will restart Apache by themselves when you install any PHP extension, other don't.

Comment: Tried that: it states I already have newest version installed.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache? If so, create a PHP file with this content: `<?php phpinfo() ?>` on your `DocumentRoot` and open it on your browser. Look for mbstring there.

Comment: "Additional .ini files parsed" section has `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini` in it; no other occurencies of `mbstring` I can see.
Yep, I restarted Apache by `apachectl restart`, but it didn't seem to help.